# Слово "юродивый"

Tags: этимология

А какая этимология у слова "юродивый"? Здесь корень "-род-"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В современном языке корень здесь юрод- (тоже что урод-)
Из этимологичесого словаря: УРОД <чел. с физическими недостатками>. Вероятно, общеслав. Образовано, полагают, с пом. прист. у- в отрицат. знач. от сущ. родъ <семья, 
род>, <порода> и значит как бы врожденный не в род>, <чем-то отличающий- 
ся от остальных в роду> (как положительным, так и отрицат.), отсюда в 
одних языках положительная окраска семантики (ср. польск. uroda <красо- 
та, миловидность>; укр. врдда <красота, краса>, где в- - вариант у-, врод-
лйвий, уродлйвий <красивый, пригожий>), а в других - нейтральная или 
отрицат., как в рус. диал. урода <стать, стан, природа>, литерат. урод 
<чел. с физическими недостатками>. Ср. др.-рус. уродъ <глупец, безумец>, 
<юродивый>; ст.-сл. юродъ (с призвуком /-) - тожд., производное от него с 
суф. -ив- прил. юродивый <глупый, неразумный>, которое впоследствии 
стало употребляться и как сущ. юродивый со знач. <нищий, безумец, об- 
ладающий даром прорицания> (устар.).